# Why is this sentence grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, sentence-patterns

I have been practicing sample tests for an English Olympiad and came across such a question:

**Decide if the sentence is correct or incorrect.**

> *After you make your payment, the products will be sent to your address.*

The keys say this sentence is incorrect. But what exactly makes this sentence grammatically wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What misplaced modifier?

Comment: @Stacy It's possible that they want the perfect tense in the adjunct "After you have made your payment ..."

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong with the sentence. After seeing BillJ's comment, yes, you could use _have made_ But anybody who thinks the given sentence is "incorrect" is suffering from the bogus idea that language is something somebody made up and put in a book, rather than something that people speak.

Comment: Anybody who thinks that sentences like the given sentence are "incorrect" is usually suffering from the bogus idea that language is something somebody made up and put in a **specific** book, rather than something that people speak. // 'After making your payment, the products will be sent to your address' is more contentious.

Comment: What difference does it make to use _have made_ instead of _make_, by the way?

Comment: @405 Some would say even better ... but the original is also idiomatic. // 'When you have made ...' is probably what some prescriptivists are after.

Comment: A small point but I would not use the comma after 'payment'.

Comment: It sounds like this particular English Olympiad is not up to international standards. What country is this Grammar Bee taking place in? P.S. If you haven't figured it out yet, the sentence is not incorrect. You are right.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you mean the difference between "English like what she is spoke" and "English like what she is writted about"?

Comment: @BoldBen— Why would you omit the comma when it's ok to put it there? A stylistic choice, perhaps?

Comment: @BoldBen Sexist.

Comment: ... @405 It's not incorrect, but it (a) is unnecessary, not necessary to clarify; (b) is a little old-fashioned; (c) doesn't mirror the way many would say this out aloud. Some would read it out with a comma-sized pause, and they _should_ include the comma. // With longer strings on either side of the possible comma, the comma is better included to aid parsing (and possibly allow a pause for breath).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nah, not sexist, just using "English" as a feminine noun like "ship".

Comment: @BoldBen You're sailing close to the wind.

Comment: @JohnLawler, this is an international Olympiad. Aligned to the Common European Framework of Reference for Languages (CEFR), Internationally recognised and Ofqual regulated English language qualifications are used throughout the Olympiad. And yeah, I feel extremely confused now. How shall I know what exactly THEY consider to be correct?

Comment: Good question. Sounds pretty dubious to me. So this is happening in a European country? With participants from all over Europe?